# Installation Error in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation

I have an error when I try to install both 32-bit Lubuntu and Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not sure what this means, but the install process seems to get stuck there and doesn't continue. I've waited for upwards of half an hour for it to proceed. I'm running a fresh install of VirtualBox on Windows 7 with a 64-bit processor. Not sure what's going on.

[image: error install]

Comment: What is the text above that? Press shift-PageUp.

Comment: That's basically the whole thing.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of VirtualBox?

Comment: and do you have virtualbox extension

Comment: 32Bit for less than 2GB RAM (14.04 LTS, downloaded something like 2 hours ago) and VirtualBox 4.3.12. Now I'm getting "Spurious NAK on isa0060" and "random: nonblocking pool initiated"...

Comment: So is it booting ok now? "Spurious NAK on isa0060" is just a warning and can be ignored, "random: nonblocking pool initiated" is expected.

Comment: Nope, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the guest OS is crashing. Try to create the VM from scratch using the default settings that appear after you select version of operating system. Also make sure that 3D Acceleration is turned off in the VM before installing (you can re-enable it after you install the guest additions).

Answer (score 0):

Crashing your guest os is related to your virtualbox settings.
Your computer is not supported which you have enabled in your virtualbox settings
Such as

```
**3D Acceleration** Turned off it.
**2D Acceleration** Turned off it.
**Enable I/O APIC** Turned off it.
```

If your motherboard supports hardware Virtualization  then enable Virtualization settings in BIOS.